# generate list of A predetermined amount of dates in only specified days of week and excluding specific list of dates using google script

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets

I want to make a [list of meetings/lessons (in google sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17F50KZVz6oVFEXIt80JdsxGK1zGRIL1j49njOO0XISI/edit?usp=sharing) which recurring at sundays and wednesdays only (for example), except holidays and/ot other predefined dates. the list of "holidays" may be growing, so the list must skip this days and always stay on 69 meetings/lessons
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6QRg.png)
the simple function in cell A3 and so on like:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=1,A2+3,A2+4)
```

won't work properly because it doesn't know skip list of holidays.
and

```
=WORKDAY.INTL()
```

won't work because can't apply to only sunday,wednesday.
so I must create a script that uses same rules as =WORKDAY.INTL() but teach it to use only specific weekdays.

any help be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume, we have values in cells:

- `B2` = 69 (or any number)
- `A2` = 3/9/2016 (first date)
- `C2:C` = list of dates to skip

Paste this formula into cell `A3`:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA((if(ISEVEN(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))),row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))/2*3+row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))/2*4,(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))-1)/2*3+(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))-1)/2*4+4)+A2)*(--not(regexmatch(text(if(ISEVEN(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))),row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))/2*3+row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))/2*4,(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))-1)/2*3+(row(OFFSET(A1,,,B2-1+counta(C2:C)))-1)/2*4+4)+A2,"dd/mm/yyyy ddd"), "(?i)" & JOIN("|",filter(C2:C,C2:C>0)))))),"select Col1 where Col1 > date'1900-01-01'",0)
```

The formula will expand automatically and show the result.

[image]

Numbers 3 and 4 in the formula may be changed to select another days.

Date format `"dd/mm/yyyy ddd"` in formula is to be changed to your format.

---

**Example**

Please, [try it yourself](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SvV-7EmggIjo7l9oqL09GfEyLtpKfBSFgx5pDuNowZI/edit?usp=sharing)